# How can I determine what line is causing a 404 error?

Tags: javascript, debugging, http-status-code-404

I have a terrible repeating error of 404 not found for a GET request.

The call looks like this in the JavaScript console

```
GET some_path/undefined 404 ( Not Found )
```

and all it states to the right of that is:

```
undefined:1
```

It keeps repeating over and over, it does not stop.  How can I determine what line is trying to make this call?

Comment: How are we supposed to help you without knowing any of your code?

Comment: You need to include an [mcve] in your question. Just creating that should narrow down where the issue is occurring.

Comment: I'm in the Chrome debugger, shouldn't there be a way to have the browser tell you which line it is?  I mean it's calling the error in the JavaScript console?  I have not idea what code to post at this point.  Very random error - I checked my last 5 commits and found nothing.

Comment: Have you tried pausing execution and stepping through your JavaScript?

Comment: I put a break point on my first line of application code and it is not catching it.

Comment: I thought if I was in the console it was a JS error ?

Comment: at this point I don't even know what language is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

On chrome you can add breakpoints on XHR and then you should see the callstack.
Go to developer tools -> "sources" tab -> "XHR Breakpoints" and add a breakpoint filtered by the relevant URL

Comment: try incognito window so plugins will be off, see if it changes anything

Comment: fixed.  If you get a JS error in Chrome Debugger that is all you have to do.  Google makes it easy.  Click the pause button and it will pull it up for you.  I was setting the src dynamically in JS, so it looked like xhr but was just a plain GET I think.