# requireJS throwing 404 error - how to know which file made the request?

Tags: javascript, debugging, requirejs, http-status-code-404, require

I am doing some work on a large angular application, which uses require.js.

require.js is throwing a 404 error which says:

> GET http://localhost:8080/myApp/my/filepath/jquery.js?v=1

How do I see which of my application's modules requested jquery.js? In the Network section of Chrome dev tools all I see is require.js:1809 as the Initiator of the error, but nothing further back than that.

I've come across this type of error a couple of times, and think that having an answer to this question will greatly improve my debugging skills - and hopefully others can learn from this as well.

I saw the following question here: [How can I determine what line is causing a 404 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142255/how-can-i-determine-what-line-is-causing-a-404-error) But when I try to add an XHR breakpoint "URL contains "jquery.js"" and refresh the page, it doesn't seem to be stopping at any breakpoints.

EDIT: Here is my require.config:

```
require.config({
    urlArgs: '...',
    deps: ['...'],
    paths: {...},
    shim: {}
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Please show requirejs config

Comment: Hi @TomaszJakubRup,
Thanks for the feedback. Are you referring to my main.js file, or to something in the require.js file? 
Thanks again!

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup - I have added an EDIT with require.config function. Let me know if I can provide any other info that may be of help. THanks!!!

Comment: Can You show Your FULL config? I know the structure. I need to look at the details.

Comment: Hi @TomaszJakubRup - Thanks again for your help here. May I ask what you are looking to see specifically within my config file? What are you looking for here?

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup - you previously looked at my question here, and seemed to think the answer lay in changing my require.js config file. Can you please specify what the change would be, or which section of my config file to look at? I'd love to get this resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Show **require.config** or share Your project (or full working example) on GitHub/BitBucket

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup, I cannot do that, since this is not a public project, and the project is large. Which section might be helpful to answer this question? Or perhaps you know where I can find sample code in documentation somewhere? Thanks!